# Pipewire: No sound on tv via HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi, 23.10, pipewire

Since a recent update of Ubuntu 23.10 I don't have the sound anymore on my TV when plugged on my Laptop.

I tried with another computer, a Mac one, and it's working, so it's not a cable issue.

I also tried to plug my laptop to the TV with Ubuntu 18.04 and it works.

So it's a recent issue with Pipewire.
What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the correct output device in `pavucontrol`?

Comment: pavucontrol is for pulseaudio and I use Pipewire

Comment: Pipewire is fully compatible with pulseaudio commands, including `pavucontrol`